# Asp.Net Core Unauthorized login - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, password-encryption

I don't know if my title is correct. But I have a simple problem.

I can't login. And is this because the `encrypted data` i cannot `decrypt` it properly?

Basically, I have a register method.

And this is my `AuthRepository`

```
public class AuthRepository : IAuthRepository
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public AuthRepository(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<User> Login(string username, string password)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == username);

            if (user == null)
                return null;

            if (!VerifyPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
                return null;

            return user;
        }

        private bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
            {
                var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

                for (int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (computedHash[i] != passwordHash[i])
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<User> Register(User user, string password)
        {
            byte[] passwordHash, passwordSalt;
            CreatePasswordHash(password, out passwordHash, out passwordSalt);

            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

            await _context.Users.AddAsync(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return user;
        }

        private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
            {
                passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
                passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> UserExists(string username)
        {
            if (await _context.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.Username == username))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My `register` is working. I tested it using `Postman`

But why i can't login?

Is there any wrong with my `decrpyting` the `encrypted` data when the user is `registered` I've been trying to solve for hours now. But i can't make it work. I am following a video tutorial. But i can't find the difference with the one in the tutorial and mine.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthRepository _repo;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public AuthController(IAuthRepository repo, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _repo = repo;
            _config = config;
        }
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
        {
            userForRegisterDto.Username = userForRegisterDto.Username.ToLower();

            if (await _repo.UserExists(userForRegisterDto.Username))
                return BadRequest("Username already exist");

            var userToCreate = new User
            {
                Username = userForRegisterDto.Username
            };

            var createdUser = await _repo.Register(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);

            return StatusCode(201);
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
        {
            var userFromRepo = await _repo.Login(userForLoginDto.Username.ToLower(), userForLoginDto.Password);

            if (userFromRepo == null)
                return Unauthorized();


            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

I'm really stuck into this part. Please help me. Thank you.

I didn't encountered any error.

But i noticed this when i debug the program

[image]

[image]

The array result is not the same. Is this the reason of the `Unauthorized login`

If so. How can i properly validate the username and password.

I also checked if the username and password i passed in the web api is correct (plain text).

Comment: why not use the inbuilt login feature of Identity framework?

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm still new to asp.net core. So what i did is follow tutorial that i found

Comment: If you’re following a tutorial, you should at least mention that tutorial. It’s possible that the tutorial is just wrong (or outdated). – That being said, you say that you have tested your register using PostMan, but have you tried testing your `AuthRepository` directly using tests instead? Also, you mention “encrypting” and “decrypting” over and over, but you are actually doing neither of that. So it’s very difficult to see what is actually not working here.

Comment: if you can add `ErrorMessage/Exception` and Stacktrace of what's wrong that might help resolve this issue

Comment: i updated the question. kindly help me. tnx

Comment: if you are new to .net core and just learning, imho it might be better to learn the existing fully integrated framework of Microsoft: Identity.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the problem is when you are creating and comparing the object of System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512() because of this it always generate a different hash. Solution for this is to declare a global object for this class and you have to use the object when you are creating and verifying the hash. I have checked it. It working fine in my case after declaring globally.

Comment: I updated the question. On debug. The array is not the same. What code did i missed?

Comment: define the System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512() object globaly and use it. I also updated the answer. Please check if its help